# Trying to change background color to white on Xcode for swift, but appears grey. :P

Tags: swift, background

I put self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

within viewdidload function and when i run sim it still shows gray background :P

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting it in viewWillAppear and see what happen?